# When I import d3.min.js to ANGULAR4, show nv.d3.js:21 uncaught TypeError:d3.dispatch is not a function

Tags: angular, word-cloud

I just want to use angular4-word-cloud into my angular4 project to make a word cloud.
[here is my code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmujA.png)
[here is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqUey.png)

Comment: here is my code ( angular-cli.json):"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/angular4-word-cloud/d3.min.js",
      ],

Comment: I fixed it .This is due to a version issue, the NVD3 I am using is based on D3 v3+, but I cannot use D3 v4+. My plan is to also import D3 V3 and D3 v4+